# Entity that crystallizes everything it meets

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design

I’m writing a story where a plague/virus/pandemic infects a whole bunch of people and plants and crystallizes them.

Stuff to know:

- Can be any living thing that is preferably hard to see without a microscope.
- Can crystallize dead things.
- Spreads fast.

Bonus:

- Has a chance cause crystals of different sizes.
- Has a chance not to kill the victim.
- Plants and animals are still somewhat edible

How can I make that happen with minimal hand waving?

Comment: It sounds like you want a plausible version of Tiberium.

Comment: @JBH I don't read "turning a liquid or gas into a solid" in that page. It might be easier to form with liquid or gas (or plasma) because the molecules are more mobile, but as far as I know solids can form crystals too. Diamonds are a crystal as far as I know, created from pressurised coal.

Comment: @Trioxidane You're right, that's what I get for skimming while watching the election results.

Comment: A crystal as such is impossible because organic material can't form a repeating structure. Possibly you could get something metaphorically similar to cement, with lumps and bumps in a solid. But getting it to happen in more than a small range of organic things would be pretty much impossible without a *lot* of hand waving. The science based tag makes this impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. This thing infects, so it must replicate, so it must be (at least partially) alive. That makes it complex when compared to crystalline structures. That’s OK. A complex organism can easily leave behind crystalline structures in its wake or grow them as a side effect. Here we have a living thing that consumes other living things and reforms them into a more favourable crystalline structure. Sugar of some form is a good candidate, as it already shares many of the same chemical components as life, though protecting these crystals from the liquid content of the body of coming up with a reason this disease would waste energy making these crystals is left as an exercise for the reader.

The issue is that this disease must also be not only cross-species, but work across not only the whole spectrum of living things. A human is vastly different in composition, design and defence mechanisms than a tree is, and successful diseases need to be specialised in order to be effective. Lugging around all the information on how to turn a plant cell into crystal and a human cell into crystal leaves it laughably easy to destroy by either immune system.

So this isn’t a normal disease. It’s either alien in origin (and is ‘mining’ living things rather than eating them) or it’s been designed, possibly as some form of advanced nanotechnology. The latter gives more options as to why the thing does what it does, though why someone would design such a thing is beyond me. It also allows for things like mother/daughter attacks, where slow mothership cells contain the information for exploiting everything, but spawn appropriately specialised daughters when in a host.

Of course, if you go with both alien and designed then you can plausibly say it’s alien tech designed to pre-concentrate patches of resources for the alien terraforming effort. But as @Trioxidane pointed out that’s just the plot of Command and Conquer’s Tiberium saga, so perhaps not...

Comment: Could the organism make this crystal for both nutrition and protection? They can draw energy from the body for the crystals. After death of the body they will (have) put as much nutrition as possible into the crystal, in which they can reside in a hibernation or special spreader state until a new infectable target comes past?

Comment: @Trioxidane: Quite plausibly, though more efficient solutions exist for both of those things in isolation from each other.

Comment: @JoeBloggs well, plot wise its backstory is someone was trying to make something that would make people more resistant to damage by i guess making an exoskeleton or something, it went wrong and then poof apocalypse that turns everything into crystals. didnt think it was that important to the question so i left it out.

Comment: @Topcode: Adaptive nanite armour goes rogue. Sounds legit.